# where can I get a js library to implement (responsive to other points ) vertical multipoint range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, user-interface, rangeslider

actually, I want something like what the below link provides
https://observablehq.com/@a10k/component-slider but in vertical and also with many options and customizability.
[see this image to get an idea of what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB7lJ.png)

[see this too for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NruK.png)

If I can find some js library that provides similar functionality it would make my life so much easier.